# How to refresh Android Studio to show newly added resources via File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added some drawable resources (e.g strings xml for another flavor of the app) under `res/values` folder using Windows file explorer but the project file structure of Android Studio has not been updated. How can I update it without restarting Android Studio or rebuilding the project, is there a shortcut or menu for it?

Btw File/Synchronize did not help.

Comment: why you don't want to use rebuild?

Comment: Actually I am using rebuild, I just want to know if there is any other shortcut for it?

Comment: This issue doesnt hapen with me, it is always updated

Comment: Do you use File/Synchronize or is it automatically updated? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: Never touched any configuration it always worked, new files and modified external files

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason leading me to think there is a problem. Actually, when using build variants, even if you add some resources to subfolders and the chosen Build Variant through Build Variants screen is not same with the one you added resources for, the resources of this Build Variant is not visible to you and you may think Android Studio does not make the necessary updates. If the Build Variant that I have added resources for was chosen beforehand then Android Studio folder structure would be updated as soon as I made the changes.